# Tcl Syntax Highlighting Broken in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tcl, syntax-highlighting

I love VS Code, but I seem to be having an issue with Tcl syntax highlighting, sometimes it works well, but other times it seems to get confused, resulting in the picture below.  I have disabled all Tcl related extensions, is there something I am missing?

[image]

Comment: It looks really confused to me, perhaps by the `...`? I wonder what it thinks is going on. (It's also missing out on highlighting inline comments it looks like.)

Comment: I like VS Code too, I tried to reproduce the issue without success (good for me), the syntax highlighting looks fine. As an alternative you may also try SublimeText, It will not disappoint you.